# SwiftUI - Button loads views properly but then bounces between views

Tags: navigation, swiftui

Clearly I'm doing something very wrong. I have three views shown below. The first is a list of customers populated from a fetch request. Each row is a navigation link that goes to a Customer Detail View. There a "+" button that creates and saves a new quote object, then transitions to a Quote view. But as soon as it does, the Customer Detail view loads again unexpectedly and is immediately dismissed to the Customer List view.

This odd behavior is not consistent. Things work fine more often than not. And if I comment out the `makeQuoteNumber` method, the problem seems to be solved completely. I tried adding a completion handler to the `makeQuoteNumber` method since it's called right before the Quote view appears, but that did not help.

[image: views]

**Customer List**

```
List {
   ForEach(customers
      .filter({searchText.isEmpty ? true :  //code for search bar
         $0.custName?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) ?? false })) { customer in
            NavigationLink(destination: CustomerDetailView(customer: customer)) {
               CustomerRow(customer: customer)
           }
           .id(self.refreshingID) //helps refresh list when a customer is added or edited.
       }
       .onDelete(perform: deleteCustomer)
   }
```

**Customer Detail - add button**

```
VStack {
   NavigationLink(destination: QuoteView(quoteNumber: quoteNumber), isActive: $showQuoteView) { EmptyView() }
      Button(action: {
         self.CreateNewQuote(completion: {
            self.showQuoteView = true
         })
      }) {
         Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
        }
    }

func CreateNewQuote(completion: () -> ()) {
        let newQuote = Quote(context: self.moc)
        newQuote.id = UUID()
        let quoteNumber = makeQuoteNumber(usingDate: Date())
        newQuote.quoteNumber = quoteNumber
        let title = "Quote for \(customer.custName ?? "")"
        newQuote.user = user.first
        newQuote.quoteTitle = title
        customer.addToQuotes(newQuote)
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        
        self.quoteNumber = quoteNumber
        
        completion()
    }

func makeQuoteNumber(usingDate date: Date) -> String {
    let seconds = date.dateToSeconds()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMddyy"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: date)
    let quoteNumber = "QQ\(formattedDate)-\(seconds)"
    
    return quoteNumber
}

func secondsFromDate(date: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var totalSeconds = 0
    
    let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    totalSeconds = hours * 3600
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    totalSeconds += minutes * 60
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    totalSeconds += seconds
    return totalSeconds
}
```

I can show the code for the Quote View, but as part of my debugging, I replaced the entire view with a simple text view and the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided code is not testable, so just an idea - try to activate link after some delay

```
  Button(action: {
     self.CreateNewQuote(completion: {
        // DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { // or this
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.showQuoteView = true
        }
     })
```

Comment: I set the delay to 0.1 seconds and it's working perfectly. Thank you! (Again!) Someday, I would really like to know what is happening in that tenth of a second.